# SQL wildcard usage for a word in long sentence

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to understand the usage of SQL wildcards when the database column stores a longer sentence and matching criteria is a word inside it. Suppose there is a row in `TABLEA` where the `ColumnA` stores `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` (data type is `VARCHAR2` and db is `ora12c`).

I wanted to return the rows which the sentence in `ColumnA` contains the `brown` keyword. Following queries didn't return anything

`SELECT * FROM  TABLEA WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%brown'`

`SELECT * FROM  TABLEA WHERE ColumnA LIKE '_brown'`

My primary reference was  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp but I cannot seem to find a way to figure the usage of Wildcards at the end. I am glad if someone can explain me the correct usage for the problem I am addressing.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you're querying is:

Give me everything from TableA where ColumnA ends with brown

You need to add a % at the end of your criteria as well to turn it into:

Give me everything from TableA where ColumnA contains brown

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%brown%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM  TABLEA WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%brown%'
```